# How can I get the ROI intensity values?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a problem. I have an  image. I crop a region of interest (ROI) in it. Then I want to use this ROI in my further processing.

Here is the last lines of my code:

```
.
.
.
im = Image.open(input_loc)
ROI = im.crop(( left, upper, right, lower))
pygame.display.quit()
plt.imshow(ROI)
plt.show()
print ROI
```

the problem is that I do not have ROI values. when running the last line of the above code it shows:

```
<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=116x164 at 0x7FB4250B9DD0>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I get the ROI intensity values (pixel values)?

Thanks.

Comment: What format is your image?

Comment: the image I load is ` 'png'` format. the `im` in my code is `<type 'instance'>` and ROI is `<type 'instance'>`

Comment: You could try `a = np.fromfile('my_image.png', dtype=np.uint32)`. This should return a numpy array containing the pixel values.

Comment: you mean the problem is related to using `Image.open`?

Comment: Yes I believe so. If you want to work with pixel vales then you will have to load them into an array and manipulate them with numpy. Then at different stages in your code (for example creating a ROI) you can create a new array and use imshow there (imshow will plot data in the form of numpy arrays and show it as a normal image)